# Rails json include 2 instances of same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have model called Exchanges that stores a user_id of the user who created it. I can call `@exchange.user` and it returns `User.where(user_id: @exchange.user_id)`

There's also an association to show all the users who have favorited an Exchange, which can be called with `@exchange.favorite_users`

I want to return both of these, in the json response, but only the first one is being returned.

`@exchanges = Exchange.includes(:tags, :favorite_users, :user).where(approved: true)`

```
 respond_to do |format|
   format.json { render json: {data: {exchanges: @exchanges.to_json(include: [:tags, user: {:only => [:id,:slug], :methods => [:avatar_url]}, favorite_users: { only: [:id]}] ), tags: @tags.to_json }}}
 end
```

This version returns `user: {:only => [:id,:slug], :methods => [:avatar_url]}`, but not `favorite_users: { only: [:id]}`.

```
format.json { render json: {data: {exchanges: @exchanges.to_json(include: [:tags, favorite_users: { only: [:id]}, user: {:only => [:id,:slug], :methods => [:avatar_url]}] ), tags: @tags.to_json }}}
```

This one only returns `favorite_users: { only: [:id]}`, but not `user: {:only => [:id,:slug], :methods => [:avatar_url]}`

How can I return both?

Exchange Model

```
class Exchange < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :language
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :exchanges_users
  has_many :favorite_users, :through => :exchanges_users, source: :user
  has_many :tags_exchanges
  has_many :tags, :through => :tags_exchanges
end
```

Comment: I think your issue is that they are both collections of `User` objects (i.e. `where` returns a `ActiveRecord::Relation`) and thus will be labeled as `users` (one overwriting the other). Suggestions change `exchange.user` to a relationship via `belongs_to :user` or change `User.where(user_id: @exchange.id)` (which I am going to assume is a typo) to `User.find(self.user_id)` without more knowledge of your `Exchange` model (which would be a useful addition) I am afraid it may be difficult to assist further

Comment: @ engineersmnky  I updated `users` to `favorite_users` to be easier to read, and included the model. Any thoughts on how to get this to return both?

Comment: `favorite_users` are from `users` table (for db perspective)?

Comment: @ray yes, correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@exchanges.to_json(include: [
    :tags, 
    {user: {only: [:id,:slug], methods: [:avatar_url]}}, 
    {favorite_users: { only: [:id]}}
])
```

If you want to return  both of associate model, wrap an association by using {}

Brakets only use just association symbol but cannot options

Comment: Wow that worked... hours of just missing a {}... The options were returning fine, it was just ignoring the second request for the associated Users model. Thanks for the help!